# With the z/OS 3.1 zip collection not having an index html - how to create one?

Tags: mainframe, zos

The z/OS 3.1 zip collection of publications did not ship with an index html as prior versions/releases of z/OS have had. Is there an easy way to create one?

Comment: maybe add 'docs' as a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As of Oct 10 '23 early morning IBM has updated the PDX file (zip with all PDFs) with an index HTML file.

**Original Answer**

Since the 3.1 collection does not have the html file like the 2.5 collections (and prior) did there is a workable solution:

1. Download the 3.1 collection
2. copy from your 2.5 collection directory the 1.read_me... file and subdirectory into the 3.1 directory
3. Rename them from v2r5 to v3r1
4. Edit the htm file and change 2.5 to 3.1 and v2r5 to v3r1
5. save it and your good to go

Caveats - any new products/pubs that are new to 3.1 won't be there (e.g. AI, DSFS wasn't there, and probably more).

This process does not change the order number for the pubs but will fix the url for the related pdf.

As usual YMMV

Comment: as of Oct 10 early morning IBM has updated the PDX file (zip with all PDFs) with an index HTML file so this is now moot.

Comment: Lionel, you can still mark this question as answered so people will be drawn to it.  I added your comment to your answer